# Use of unresolved identifier error SpriteKit animation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create an animation in swift, and I keep getting a "Use of unresolved identifier" which I think is from the variable but I'm not sure.

I create the variables at the top of the class,

```
var textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
var textureArray = [SKTexture]()
```

I then create the setup function to add the texture animation, and the create the scene

```
func setup() {
     player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: textureAtlas.textureNames[0] as! String)

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "planetsbackgroun700@2x")
    let midPoint = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 2.0, y: self.frame.size.height / 2.0)

    background.position = midPoint

    background.setScale(2)
    //self.addChild(background)
    self.addChild(background)

    player?.position = CGPoint(x: 350, y: 350)
    player?.setScale(0.2)
    self.addChild(player!)
}
```

Then at the bottom I create the for loop to repeat the animation:

```
textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Planets Player") *error*


for i in 1...textureAtlas.textureNames.count { *error*

var Name = "PlanetsPlayer_00\(i).png"
textureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
}
```

I call for the animation when the left arrow key is pressed:

```
if leftPressed {
if playerZAcceleration < 0.1{
playerZAcceleration += 0.001
}
player?.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate
(withtextureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)))
```

I am not sure what is wrong with it, I have tried changing the variable types, and anything I can think of.  Sorry that this is a stupid question, I'm new to SpriteKit and swift.

Comment: How do you create the player variable? Is it at the top of the class?

Comment: Yeah, sorry... I forgot to add that in my question. it is right next to the texture variables.

Comment: You are also missing the colon on the last line, it should be `SKAction.animate(with: textureArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)`

Comment: Make sure you have declared the `textureAtlas` variable inside the class.

Comment: Ok I did that, that seemed to help but now I have a "expected declaration" error on the "textureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Planets Player")".

Comment: That code needs to be inside the class too :)